# NSTextField to Label by using TextField as the name of an dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode, nstextfield

Swift4, Xcode9.3, Cocoa App.

How to change the string of labelMain to a dictionary word, 
with a string key?

for example, a user put in "dict1" in the TextField,
the app should recognized that it is in the dict1 dictionary key "2",
and the label should print out "word2", instead of other words.

```
    let dict0 : Dictionary<String, String> = ["0" : "word0", "1" : "word1"]
    let dict1 : Dictionary<String, String> = ["2" : "word2", "3" : "word3"]

    labelMain.stringValue = TextField.stringValue["2"]
```

error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: I edited your question to leave your original version and to show the updated code.  Why did you roll that back?

Comment: sorry, I opened 2 tabs, and messed it up, so I updated the whole thing one more time.

Comment: The original question should be left intact and just added to.  Do you mind if we roll back to the version I had that showed both version of the code?

Comment: I don't mind, please roll it back if you want to.

Comment: Seriously, thanks you so much. You don't know how much this is helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary that maps dictionary names to the actual dictionary:

```
let dict0 : Dictionary<String, String> = ["0" : "word0", "1" : "word1"]
let dict1 : Dictionary<String, String> = ["2" : "word2", "3" : "word3"]
let dictMap = ["dict0": dict0, "dict1": dict1]

if let dict = dictMap[TextField.stringValue], let word = dict["2"] {
    labelMain.stringValue = word
}
```

or using *optional chaining*:

```
if let word = dictMap[TextField.stringValue]?["2"] {
    labelMain.stringValue = word
}
```

or combined with the *nil coalescing operator* to provide a default value if none was found:

```
labelMain.stringValue = dictMap[TextField.stringValue]?["2"] ?? ""
```

Comment: it return a string value "0" instead of "word2"

Comment: What is the value of `TextField.stringValue`.  Perhaps you left something out.  What does your code look like that got `"0"`.

Comment: I typed in dict1 in the TextField, and It just show 0 in the label.

Comment: add `print` statements for debugging.  `print(TextField.stringValue);print(dictMap[TextField.stringValue] as Any)`.  What do those show?

Comment: Optional(["2": "word2", "3": "word3"])

Comment: OK, that's what we expect to see.  Update your question with the version of the code you're using now that results in the `0` label.

Comment: Thanks you so much.